# swift playgrounds display uiview with nonstop looping

Tags: swift

I create and display uiview in live view windows, when i create the button and add to the uiview , the program fail with nonstop looping which continuously load addbutton . Did somebody meet this problem and please tell me why :-)

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

var label1 : UILabel?

override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    print("code run here ")

    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
    label.text = "Hello World!"
    label.textColor = .black

    label1 = label
    view.addSubview(label)

    let  k1:UIButton = addnewbutton() as! UIButton
    //view.addSubview(k1)

    self.view = view
}

@objc func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
   self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func addnewbutton() -> UIView{
    var btn : UIButton
    btn = UIButton()
    btn.frame  = CGRect(x:200,y:300,width:100,height:25)
    btn.setTitle("clickme",for: UIControlState.normal)
    //btn.titleLabel?.text = "clickme"
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    btn.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    btn.titleColor(for: UIControlState.normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(btn)

    return btn
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the button here

```
view.addSubview(btn)
```

inside `addnewbutton`

which recursively searches for the parent view of the VC and it's not yet setted inside `loadView` so control calls it again  and the problem happens to infinite loop , so comment that line and uncomment this

```
view.addSubview(k1) // which is inside loadView
```

BTW make the return of `addnewbutton` to `UIButton` directly instead of a cast

Comment: Also, in this case, `loadView` should not be overridden. Instead, override `viewDidLoad` and put the setup code in there.

Comment: @rmaddy it's not a wrong to make it inside **loadView** , actually xcode playground view template add hello world label inside **loadView**